# Is the more connections the better?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, download, connection, wget

I want to download 10000 different images from almost 10000 different servers. I was wondering how many files I should download asynchronously.

I've seen before with `lftp pget` how making multiple connections for downloading one file can be much faster if the server provides enough bandwidth. I was wondering if there is a trade-off for making too many asynchronous connections to many different servers at the same time. And how I can find the optimal number of connections for my system. What I want to download are images that are not so large so I was wondering how that optimal number would change if instead I wanted to download so many pdf files or other larger files from different servers. I was also wondering how that would change on `wifi` vs `Ethernet`.

```
$ uname -srpo
Linux 4.13.0-26-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

$ lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```